# windows service not persisting object state

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created a win service that has this method on start:

```
private String bamboo = "";
public String Baboon = "";

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.bamboo = "bamboo";
    this.baboon = "baboon";
}
```

after the service starts i have methods for returning the field and the property:

```
public String GetValueBamboo()
{
    return this.bamboo;
}

public String GetValueBaboon()
{
    return this.Baboon;
}
```

these methods return empty strings when i try to get the values from another app:

```
public void GetValues()
{
    var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
    var epAddrs = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse");

    var pipeFactory =
        new ChannelFactory<ITaskManager>(
        binding,
        epAddrs);

    var proxy =
        pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

    Assert.AreEqual(proxy.GetValueBamboo(),"bamboo"); // returns false
    Assert.AreEqual(proxy.GetValueBaboon(),"baboon"); // returns false
}
```

I have noticed that if i use the same proxy object to first set the values of the field/property(didn't write those methods, pretty straightforward), then the results come out as expected but every call after with a new proxy object again returns empty strings.

is there a way that i can set some properties and/or fields on the service and that they persist between calls to the service?

Comment: What is implementing ITaskManager in your service?

Comment: @CoreTech A class in my windows service project. the class also inherits ServiceBase.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i ended up using is just to declare the fields static, and then it works.

I would still like to know why instanced fields in a service reset after reinitializing the client, so if anyone has any idea about this I would very much like to know.